Description about Sri Rangam Vimanam
Why is it called Pranava Akara Vimanam?
Does it have any scriptural backing or just hearsay and Sthala Puranam?
this article the Vimanam of SriRangam is called Pranavakara Vimanam.
I need any scriptural evidence for this.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Mahadeva https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ananda_Nilayam in this article the Vimanam of SriRangam is called Pranavakara Vimanam. I need any scriptural evidence for this.

Googled images. Found no particular Om shape resemblance  ( either in Sanskrit or in Tamil) of the SriRangam temple vimanam architecture.

@Narasimham https://www.facebook.com/templepurohit/posts/paravasudevan-at-pranavakara-vimanam-srirangam-its-under-this-sacred-and-ancient/1103326613198089/

@Narasimham https://www.facebook.com/watch?v=1549918495028028

Can you see anything like that guy is saying?

The same word Vimaana denotes two things. First, the uppermost architectural part of a temple peak that is stationary. Second, an actual flying or moving plane like the Pushpaka Vimaanam ( as per some references it  runs on mercury as a propellant ) that has decorations with Om symbol etc.. Temple top floor is the aerodrome platform for people emplaning and  I suspect the second one, which we now obviously cannot see, is what is  described in Ekaantika's answer Chapter 25... Alternately  ( just as beauty is in the eyes of the beholder ) a staunch Bhaktha's devotion  sees more than the others.

narasimha puraNa has the story of ranganatha vimAna :

narasimha puraNa ch. 25
51-54. O king, under inspiration of that  inexpressive voice, I gave up that ceaseless  penance and created the living organisms of  this
world. On completion of that project,  Prajapati Visvakarma appeared
in my heart  in a relaxed state. He made two radiant  icons of god
Visnu and Sesanaga known as  Ananta. O king, those portraits were
made  of the same posture and sentiments as I had  seen of god at that
time. Since then I used to  worship those icons and by virtue of the
blessing so indirectly obtained from god, I  could acquire knowledge,
ever pleasing and  started living peacefully and in the state of
emancipation.
55-59. O the king of kings, I am going to tell  you the benevolent way. Listen to it and as  per my words give up this severe penance to
which you are performing this time and go back to your kingdom. It is
the foremost  religion and penance of kings to take care of  their
subjects. I will send that aircraft  (vimana) containing that icon to
you with  siddha and Brahmanas. Do the worship of  god in the
prescribed manner for extraneous  or physical adoration. O the great
king, do  worship of that god sleeping on Sesanaga  known as Ananta
duly performing the  offerings without any expressive desire in  the
mind (Niskamabhava) and take care of  your subjects. O king, you will
definitely  avail of emancipation by the grace of god  Vasudeva. "With
these words Brahma  returned to his abode."
60-66. O Brahmana, on departure of god  Brahma, as Iksvaku was about to think over  his suggestions, the aircraft (vimana) given  by
Brahma suddenly appeared with the  icons of Ananta and Visnu along
with  Siddha Brahmanas before him. He saluted  with great reverence
the icons and bowed  his head before the Brahmins came in that
aircraft. Then he took the aircraft to his  kingdom. All men and women
of that  kingdom saw the king and they took him  spreading flowers
(lava) on the way. The  king installed that Vaisnava aircraft at his
giant temple and began to worship the icon  of god Visnu as the same
was worshipped  by the Brahmins come in that aircraft. His  queens
used to make garlands of scented  flowers for the icon which pleased
the king.  The citizens too began to bring camphor,  sandal, kumkum,
aguru etc., fragrances and  clothes, gugula and special flowers for
god  Visnu's worship.
67-72. The king used to worship god Visnu,  seated on the aircraft in the morning, noon  and in the evening with obeisance. He did  japa,
recited the hymns, praise of his mercy  and piping of conch-shell and
other musical  instruments himself and made others to do  the same, in
his realm. He used to arrange function at nights and the procession of
god  duly trimmed according to the manner  prescribed by the
scriptures. The king  acquired the supreme knowledge by the  grace of
god Visnu with his religious acts,  the offerings, donations etc. He
reproduced  sons in order to maintain the rites exercised  by him as
to perform offerings, ruling and  for satiation of Pitras coincide
continuous  worship of god. He attained the abode of  god Visnu merely
by extracting the  breathings through concentration on the  Brahma.
Thus king Iksvaku attained to the  position of god Visnu, who is Aja,
Asoka,  Amala, holy, tranquil and in the form of  truth, chid and
pleasure (Saccidananda) by  kicking off the limitless pain giving
world.
narasimha puraNa ch. 26
10-11. Rama, in pursuance of the words of his  father began observing penance in  Dandakaranya with his brother Laksmana  and wife Sita.
Ravana, in that forest  abducted his wife Sita. Aggrieved at this,
Rama in the company of his brother tied  with Sugriva in friendship,
took him with  his crores of army consisting of monkeys  and bears,
constructed a bridge on the giant  sea and thus entered into Lanka. He
killed  that suppressor of gods with his relations  and the army, got
Sita again and returned to  Ayodhya. Bharata, his younger brother
enthroned him. Rama gifted Vibhlsana an  aircraft containing an icon
of the god Visnu and the kingdom of Lanka and thus, bade  farewell.
The icon of god Visnu in spite of  being carried by Vibhlsana with him
duly  enshrined on the aircraft, was reluctant to  live in Lanka. He
therefore, automatically  installed at the holy forest developed by
Vibhlsana beyond the border of that state.  There, the god sleeps on
the body of the  giant serpent. Vibhlsana could not pick up  that
aircraft from there. He then, departed to  Lanka leaving the icon of
Visnu there in  compliance with the suggestion of the god.
12. The place was turned into a great holy  place because of the presence of god  Narayana. It is still famous as Srlraranga
kshetra. The subsequent descendants were-  Lava, Padma, Rtuparna,
Astrapani,  Suddhodana and lastly Budha. Budha was  the last
descendant of the solar clan and it  ceased onward.


It doesn't answer my question though. Why is the Vimanam called Pranavakara Vimanam?
